# How are floats are converted to hex - decompiling using apktool 

Tags: android, apk

When decompiling an apk using apktool, I found an array of doubles are converted to the code below. How does the apktool do that?

```
:array_0
 .array-data 0x8
     0xc7t 0x55t 0x9at 0xf4t 0x6dt 0x5bt 0x44t 0x40t
     0xfet 0x6t 0xdat 0x35t 0x7et 0x5bt 0x44t 0x40t
     0xd4t 0x57t 0x45t 0xf8t 0x59t 0x5bt 0x44t 0x40t
     0xf6t 0xe8t 0xaat 0x3et 0x4et 0x5bt 0x44t 0x40t
     0xc7t 0x55t 0x9at 0xf4t 0x6dt 0x5bt 0x44t 0x40t
 .end array-data
```

Comment: If you post the contents of your original array, it will be pretty easy to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built a sample program and decompiled it. The numbers are doubles, one per row. Each double is encoded in [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE754) format, with the LSB first. My array us defined as:

```
double array[]={ 0, 1, 0.5, 2 };
```

The resulting baksmali looks like this:

```
:array_0
.array-data 0x8
    0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t
    0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0xf0t 0x3ft
    0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0xe0t 0x3ft
    0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x0t 0x40t
.end array-data
```

Since the IEEE754 representation of 1 is `0x3ff0000000000000`, we can conclude that doubles are stored in little endian IEEE754.

If all you want is to convert the numbers in your program, you can use an [online converter](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html?hexadecimal=40445B6DF49A55C7) (in this link with your first double already fed in).

Shachar

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention whether you are just trying to understand, or whether apktool simply failed to decompile an APK for you. If the later, I wrote a "competing" tool called [zzos](https://github.com/Shachar/Lingnu-Android-Tools), which might just work better for you.

If you are interested in the format, please understand that Android contains more than one floating point format. Floating points are sometimes stores as IEEE standard format, but sometimes they are stored in other, almost fixed point, formats. The precise meaning of the "doubles" you quote really depends on where they are taken from, and how they were encoded.

The simplest way to try and understand those is to run "aapt d --values resources *apkfile*" over your APK, and search there for the values. If you paste the relevant part of the result here, we can try and help you understand exactly what is going on, and I can try to point you to the right place that encodes there.

Shachar

Comment: Please disregard. I just re-read the question, and it seems that you are asking about the decompilation of the dex, not of the resources. I don't have an answer off hand for you, but you should understand that this is not apktool doing the decompilation, but baksmali.